# Variance for uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, variance

I have to calculate the variance:

> $\mathsf{Var}(aX + bY + cZ + d)$

I know that a,b,c,d are positive and that $X, Y$ and $Z$ have a common uniform distribution on $\big\{(x,y,z) \in \{0,3\}^3: x + y + z\text{ is a twofold}\big\}$.

The question is to calculate $\mathsf{Var}(aX + bY + cZ + d)$

I used the common rules to calculate the variance but I don't see why the solution must be

> ${\mathsf{Var}(aX + bY + cZ + d) } = {a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)  + b^2\mathsf{Var}(Y) + c^2\mathsf{Var}(X) \\+ ab\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y) + ac\mathsf{Cov}(X,Z) + bc\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Z)}$

Can anyone help me with this? I assume that X, Y, and Z are numbers and dependent.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$

Comment: This question seems to be more about generic properties of the variance rather than about the uniform distribution itself. The mapping $(X,Y) \mapsto \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ (covariance of $X$ and $Y$) is _bilinear_. The variance, $X \mapsto \mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$ is the _quadratic form_ associated to $\mathrm{Cov}$. This is why, when you expand $\mathrm{Var}(aX+bY)$, you obtain: $a^2 \mathrm{Var}(X) + b^2 \mathrm{Var}(Y) + 2ab \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$.

Comment: I don't understand the distributional assumption.  What does *twofold* mean in this context.  Is $X$ a number or a vector?  Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? And so on.

Comment: @kimchilover Quite so. But it seems we shall never know...

Comment: @kimchilover Sorry, but that's the task we recieved.  I assume that X en Y ar numbers and that they are dependent. I don't really know what twofold means too. Sorry.

Comment: Does it perhaps mean the sum of the three ordinates is *even*?

Comment: Or maybe $(X,Y,Z)$ is a uniformly distributed  point from the 2-simplex,  according to what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) calls $\operatorname{Dir}(1,1,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression isn't quite right. There should be $2$'s in front of every covariance term. It might help to first derive the following expression for two random variables:

Var($aX + bY$) = $a^2$Var($X$) + $b^2$Var($Y$) + $2ab$Cov($X,Y$)

As a start,

Var($aX + bY$) = $\mathbb{E}[(aX + bY - a\mu_X - b\mu_Y)^2] \\
= \mathbb{E}[(aX - a\mu_X)^2] + \mathbb{E}[(bY - b\mu_Y)^2] + 2\mathbb{E}[(aX - a\mu_X)(bY - b\mu_Y)]$

Comment: The fact that x + y + z is a twofold? Maybe that's the reason why there isn't a 2 in front of every covariance term?

Comment: @EvaVandenberghe No, it is just that you miscopied the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hinging on the interpretation of "$x+y+z$ is a twofold" means "the sum of the terms is even".

$$\{(x,y,z)\in\{0,3\}^3: (x+y+z)\in2\Bbb Z\} = \{(0,0,0),(0,3,3),(3,0,3),(3,3,0)\}$$

Of course, if "twofold" means something else, you will have a different set.   Once you have determined what set you have, you can evaluate the variance of each variable, and covariances of each pair.

---

From there it is a matter of using the bilinearity of covariance, which infers: $$\def\Var{\mathsf{Var}} \def\Cov{\mathsf{Cov}} \Var(aX+bY+cZ+d)~{=~{a^2\Var(X)+b^2\Var(Y)+c^2\Var(Z) \\+ 2ab\Cov(X,Y)+2ac\Cov(X,Z)+2bc\Cov(Y,Z)} }$$